# can not display the value of a property inside an object API

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my API it has an object type, I want to access Id inside the IdList which is inside the eSearchResult
[This is a caption of the api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0b8Ha.png)

```
query 
{_declaration: {…}, _doctype: 'eSearchResult PUBLIC "-//NLM//DTD esearch 20060628…/20060628/.."', eSearchResult: {…}}
eSearchResult:
Count: {_text: '6'}
IdList: {Id: Array(6)}
QueryTranslation: {_text: '("Science"[Journal] OR "Science (1979)"[Journal]) …]) OR "breast cancer"[All Fields]) AND 2008[pdat]'}
RetMax: {_text: '6'}
RetStart: {_text: '0'}
TranslationSet: {Translation: Array(2)}
TranslationStack: {TermSet: Array(10), OP: Array(13)}
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

and this is my code

```
{query.length &&
        Object.keys(query.eSearchResult.IdList.Id).map((keyName, index) => (
          <div>
            <div>
              <div className="card bg-c-blue order-card">
                <div className="card-block" key={index}>
                  <h6 className="text-left">
                    <span>Frequency: {index}</span>
                    {console.log("index", index)}
                    {query.eSearchResult.IdList.Id[keyName]}
                  </h6>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
```

Any ideas please

Answer (score 0):

`query` is an object, not an array, `query.length` is always false, the code after `query.length &&` will not be excuted